# Pandas: How to read ill formated time data?

Tags: python, pandas

The time of my dataframe consist of 2 coloumns: `date` and `HrMn`, like this:

[image]

How can I read them into time, and plot a time series plot? (There are other value columns, for example, `speed`).

I think I can get away with `time.strptime('19900125'+'1200','%Y%m%d%H%M')`

But the problem is that, when read from the `csv`, `HrMn` at `0000` would be parsed as `0`, so 
`time.strptime('19900125'+'0','%Y%m%d%H%M')` will fail.

UPDATE:

My current approach:

```
# When reading the data, pase HrMn as string
df = pd.read_csv(uipath,header=0, skipinitialspace=True, dtype={'HrMn': str})
df['time']=df.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime("{0} {1}".format(x['date'],x['HrMn']), "%Y%m%d %H%M"),axis=1)# df.temp_date
df.index= df['time']
# Then parse it again as int
df['HrMn'] = df['HrMn'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I think this will just work if you did: `df = pd.read_csv(uipath,header=0, skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=[['time','HrMn']])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) after you've transformed it into a string that looks like a date:

```
def to_date_str(r):
    d = r.date[: 4] + '-' + r.date[4: 6] + '-' + r.date[6: 8]
    d += ' '+ r.HrMn[: 2] + ':' + r.HrMn[2: 4]
    return d

>>> pd.to_datetime(df[['date', 'HrMn']].apply(to_date_str, axis=1))
0   1990-01-25 12:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Edit**

As @EdChum comments, you can do this even more simply as

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str) + df.HrMn)
```

which string-concatenates the columns.

Comment: I'd concatenate the columns and then parse rather than call `apply` `pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['HrMn'])`

Comment: @EdChum Super cool! I never would have guessed that `to_datetime` would grok this. Thanks!

Comment: also you can call `astype` rather than `map`: `df['date'].astype(str)` not sure if faster but this is the preferred method for `dtype` conversion

Comment: Thanks again, @EdChum

Answer (score 2):

You may parse the dates directly while reading the CSV, where `HrMn` is zero padded as HHMM, i.e. a value of 0 will represent `00:00`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    uipath,
    header=0,
    skipinitialspace=True,
    dtype={'HrMn': str},
    parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'HrMn']},
    date_parser=lambda x, y: pd.datetime.strptime('{0}{1:04.0f}'.format(x, int(y)),
                                                  '%Y%m%d%H%M'),
    index_col='datetime'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don' get why you call it "ill formatted", that format is actually quite common and pandas can parse it as is, just specify which columns you want to parse as timestamps.

```
df = pd.read_csv(uipath, skipinitialspace=True,
                 parse_dates=[['date', 'HrMn']])
```

Comment: It reports "['date' 'HrMn'] not in index", I don't know why?

Comment: Well details depend of your exact csv file, that I do not have. See my edit, based on the code you posted before I think this should work. But I have nothing to test with so can't be sure.